# What does now mean in the output of apt as well as repository repeated?

Tags: debian, apt

When `apt` lists packages, it shows package name, repo, and then `now`. What does this `now` mean?

Also, it repeats repository on some packages. Ex: `oldstable,oldstable`. What does this mean?

Comment: Can you please [edit] to show an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

In the output of `apt list`, `now` indicates that either the package is installed or you have a local, cached version of the package.

Repated `oldstable`s means that multiple architectures of the same package version are available from that suit.